# return an object with key and value using map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a response that should need to return an object with specified key and value using map

I tried

```
response.data.data = response.data.data.map((user) =>{
  return console.log({ user.id : user.name});
});
```

But it gives me an error due to `user.id`

how can i set the key coming from response?

this is my data response

```
data: [
{
    id: 2,
    name: "Orval McLaughlin",
    email: "okoch@example.org",
    contacts: "09083692343",
    created_at: "2018-09-05 15:08:54",
    updated_at: "2018-09-05 15:08:54",
    deleted_at: null
}
],
```

i am using a vue js input tag where in I need a data to bind in a prop
like this

```
{2: Orval McLaughlin}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: syntax error unexpected token, expected ,

Comment: Post what is in response.data.data

Comment: edited question

Comment: `{2: Orval McLaughlin}` should probably be `{"2": "Orval McLaughlin"}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not make sense to use `return console.log(whatever)` inside your mapping function because as that will always return `undefined` `.map()` will create an array of `undefined` entries:

```js
let users = [{ id: 1, name: "r2d2" }]

let arr = users.map(user => console.log({ id: user.id, name: user.name}))

console.log(arr);
```

Instead, change your mapping function to this:

```js
let users = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "Orval McLaughlin",
    email: "okoch@example.org",
    contacts: "09083692343",
    created_at: "2018-09-05 15:08:54",
    updated_at: "2018-09-05 15:08:54",
    deleted_at: null
}]

let arr = users.map(user => ({ [user.id]: user.name }))

console.log(arr);
```

To create a property on an object whose property name you have in a variable `propName`, use the square brackets notation:

```
let user = { [propName]: value }
```

Note that you can also access the property of an object using this notation:

```
console.log(user[propName]);
```

Answer (score 3):

To get results like

```
{2: Orval McLaughlin}
```

you want a computed property name:

```
return { [user.id] : user.name};
```

Note that `return console.log(somValue)` always returns undefined

Comment: `{2: Orval McLaughlin}` isn't that supposed to be `{2: "Orval McLaughlin"}`?

Comment: @connexo well actually it would be `{"2": "Orval McLaughlin"}`...note keyword *"like"*

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` returns `undefined`, so your current solution gives an array of all `undefined`s. Instead, you should return the object that you want:

```
response.data.data = response.data.data.map((user) =>{
  return { [user.id] : user.name};
});
```

Note that you also need to surround the user id key with brackets in order to evaluate the variable.